# Autofac object lifetime scope in self-hosted WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, autofac

I have a WCF service that is hosted in a windows service. It shares the same libraries as an ASP.NET project. The WCF service is used to process long running operations that I don't want the ASP.NET site running. I'm using Autofac to handle dependencies in both the ASP.NET and WCF project. Since I'm using ASP.NET, I'm using the InstancePerLifeTimeScope() method on all registrations. Since these same registration modules are also used in the WCF service, I was hoping they would create instances per WCF method call, but that is not happening. Is there a way to get Autofac to consider an object's lifetime scope the same as the life time as a service call?

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Autofac service hosting mechanism, if you register your service-related objects as InstancePerDependency and [set your InstanceContextMode to PerCall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734715.aspx), each call should get its own dependencies resolved. Autofac doesn't have an explicit "per call" lifetime setting for WCF.